# Why can not use Dstream.transform() with ssc.checkpoint() in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

When I try to use DStream.transform with ssc.checkpiont:

```
initRDD = sc.parallelize(list('aeiou')).map(lambda x: (x, 100)).persist()

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, batchDuration=3)
ssc.checkpoint('checkpoint')

lines = ssc.socketTextStream('localhost', 9999)
items = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
counts = items.countByValue().transform(lambda x:x.join(initRDD)).mapValues(sum)
counts.pprint()
```

There is an Exception:

> It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an
>   RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions
>   can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other
>   transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() *
>   x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action
>   cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more
>   information, see SPARK-5063.

But if I comment ssc.checkpoint:

```
# ssc.checkpoint('checkpoint')
```

The code can work as well

Comment: It seems to be an open bug in PySpark. Apparently, same issue doesn't exist in Scala. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27894